# How do I export a gltf that works with Andorid scene-viewer?

Tags: three.js, stl, gltf

I'm trying to use three.js to convert existing stls to gltf for use with the Android scene viewer (model-viewer component).  However, the gltf I export fails to work with https://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer-preview with the error message "The glTF contains a vertex color, which is not supported by the Scene Viewer specification."  It also fails when I load on an android phone using the model-viewer component, when I hit the AR button.

If I export a simple cube BoxBufferGeometry as gltf, that works in scene-viewer.  However if I export a BoxGeometry (not Buffered) that also gives the vertex color error.

How do I tell three.js to not include vertex colors in the exported gltf?

The below code is what I'm using - the exportGLTF function is copied from the three.js examples.  The stl file is just somthing simple I created from fusion 360.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.load( 'table.stl', function ( geometry ) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
    exportGLTF(mesh);
}, undefined, function ( error ) {

    console.error( error );

} );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
cube.name = "Cube";
scene.add( cube );
exportGLTF(cube);
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, three.js will not help you convert a vertex colored mesh into a textured mesh, since that involves a UV "unwrapping" step that is usually done in something like Blender or MeshLab. If you don't actually care about the colors, you could strip the colors out of the Geometry in three.js before exporting to glTF.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  I'm pretty clueless when it comes to 3d modeling, I'll look into what unwrapping is/does.  In the short term, stripping colors would be fine.  Any tips you have on how to do that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the vertex colors, you can just delete that attribute from the BufferGeometry that STLLoader produces. I found that Scene Viewer also doesn't like that the geometry is non-indexed. You can work around that with the mergeVertices function in BufferGeometryUtils.

Here's a working example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/chartreuse-steed

```js
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.load(
  stlUrl,
  function(geometry) {
    // Delete vertex colors, since Scene Viewer doesn't support them.
    geometry.deleteAttribute("color");

    // Apparently Scene Viewer also doesn't support non-indexed geometry,
    // so we do this mergeVertices operation just to get an indexed geometry
    geometry = THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices(geometry);

    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
    material.vertexColors = THREE.VertexColors;

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(mesh);

    exportGLTF(mesh);
  },
  undefined,
  function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked great.  The produced gltf file now loads in scene-viewer-preview without any warnings, so this answers the question.  Unfortunately, it still fails in the model-viewer component, so if you have any guidance there, it would be appreciated.